# Set the locale for `Date.prototype.toLocaleString` for Jest tests

Tags: javascript, jestjs

We have front-end engineers around the world, so when we run `Date.prototype.toLocaleString`, we get different results. Sometimes, these differences show up in Jest tests. If someone in a different country runs a Jest test, it may fail because of `toLocaleString`. What are some ways to force Jest to use a certain locale?

As a bandaid solution, I added the following to the failing tests:

```
  const toLocaleString = Date.prototype.toLocaleString;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-extend-native
  Date.prototype.toLocaleString = function(locale = 'en-US', ...args) {
    return toLocaleString.call(this, locale, ...args);
  };
```

Comment: Since you just need to adjust for testing, it's better to change system locale before testing.

Comment: I think this is okay. You are already mocking the date itself. Another common scenario is to mock `Date.now`. So I think this is not such a "bandaid" solution after all.

Answer (score 11):

You should add `full-icu` to your dev dependencies:

`npm i full-icu --save-dev`

And run your tests like this:

`NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest`

So if you're running a npm script you package.json will look like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "...",
   "test": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu jest",
 },
```

In case of using React Scripts:

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "...",
   "test": "NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu react-scripts test",
 },
```

And if you are using Jest VSCode extension you'll have to change this configuration:

```
`"jest.pathToJest": "npm run test --"`
```

Comment: Why it can helps me?

Comment: The node server jest run on does not have full internationalization capabilities. So it doesn't format the string correctly because it doesn't find the locale in node to do it.

Comment: Thank you! Clear solution and doesn't require any code changes (as opposed to introducing the intl package and entirely losing the native toLocaleString calls).

Comment: I want my test to always use GMT time zone so it doesn't fail when the test is run in a different time zone. Will this work for me?

Comment: After installing it, how can i set the desired locale for my tests?